# listboxitem with listbox recursive

Tags: wpf

I have a listboxitemtemplate that contains controls in a grid and a list box.
That listbox's  listboxitemtemplate contains the same controls in the grid prior.
I am looking for a way to datatemplate the listboxitemtemplate so that datatemplate can be used as the contenttemplate in both of the two listboxes.
But  I am running into dead end because the second listbox is located in the first listbox's listitemtemplate. Below is the code.
If any one has any ideas how so I can where I could come up with a scheme to datatemplate the first listbox's listboxitemtemplate minus the second listbox, and use the same datatemple in the second listbox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbLista" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxCollection}"
        >
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <dxe:TextEdit  Grid.Column="0"
                 Text="{Binding Section}"
                 TextWrapping="NoWrap" />

            <dxe:ToggleSwitch 
                 Grid.Column="1"
                  />

            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Text ="{Binding SectionText}" />


            <dxe:TextEdit  Grid.Column="3"
                   Text ="{Binding SectionStatus}" />

            <dx:DXExpander
                   Grid.Row="1" 
                   Grid.Column="0">
                   <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Purple">
                    <dxre:RichEditControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
                        <dxre:RichEditControl.HorizontalRulerOptions>
                            <dxre:DXRichEditHorizontalRulerOptions Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        </dxre:RichEditControl.HorizontalRulerOptions>
                        <dxre:RichEditControl.VerticalRulerOptions>
                            <dxre:DXRichEditVerticalRulerOptions Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        </dxre:RichEditControl.VerticalRulerOptions>
                    </dxre:RichEditControl>
                    
                     <ListBox x:Name="lbListb" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxCollectionb}" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                             <Grid>
                               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <ColumnDefinition/>
                                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                                 <ColumnDefinition/>
                                 <ColumnDefinition/>
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <dxe:TextEdit  Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding Section}"
                                   TextWrapping="NoWrap" />

                              <dxe:ToggleSwitch 
                                Grid.Column="1" />

                              <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                Text ="{Binding SectionText}" />


                             <dxe:TextEdit  Grid.Column="3"
                                Text ="{Binding SectionStatus}" />


                        <dx:DXExpander
                           Grid.Row="1" 
                               Grid.Column="0">
         

                             <DockPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                              <dxre:RichEditControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
                                <dxre:RichEditControl.HorizontalRulerOptions>
                                   <dxre:DXRichEditHorizontalRulerOptions Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                </dxre:RichEditControl.HorizontalRulerOptions>
                               <dxre:RichEditControl.VerticalRulerOptions>
                                  <dxre:DXRichEditVerticalRulerOptions Visibility="Hidden"/>
                               </dxre:RichEditControl.VerticalRulerOptions>
                              </dxre:RichEditControl>                       
                        </DockPanel>
                           </dx:DXExpander>
              </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                 </DockPanel>
               </dx:DXExpander>
           </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding Hierarchical object data to ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003026/binding-hierarchical-object-data-to-listbox)

Comment: Also take a look to the [HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=net-5.0)